# Power Spectrum and Autocorrelation of Data in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft, correlation

I am interested in computing the power spectrum of a system of particles (~100,000) in 3D space with Python. What I have found so far is a group of functions in Numpy (`fft`,`fftn`,..) which compute the discrete Fourier transform, of which the square of the absolute value is the power spectrum. My question is a matter of how my data are being represented - and truthfully may be fairly simple to answer.

The data structure I have is an array which has a shape of (*n*,2), *n* being the number of particles I have, and each column representing either the x, y, and z coordinate of the *n* particles. The function I believe I should be using it the `fftn()` function, which takes the discrete Fourier transform of an *n*-dimensional array - but it says nothing about the format. How should the data be represented as a data structure to be fed into `fftn`?

Here is what I've tried so far to test the function:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DATA = np.zeros((100,3))

for i in range(len(DATA)):
    DATA[i,0] = random.uniform(-1,1)
    DATA[i,1] = random.uniform(-1,1)
    DATA[i,2] = random.uniform(-1,1)

FFT = np.fft.fftn(DATA)
PS = abs(FFT)**2

plt.plot(PS)
plt.show()
```

The array entitled `DATA` is a mock array, ultimately the thing which will be 100,000 by 3 in shape. The output of the code gives me something like:
[image]

As you can see, I think this is giving me three 1D power spectra (1 for each column of my data), but really I'd like a power spectrum as a function of radius.

Does anybody have any advice or alternative methods/packages they know of to compute the power spectrum (I'd even settle for the two point autocorrelation function).

Comment: Are you taking the FFT across the locations? I don't know why you'd do this. The assumptions about the FFT is that you data is regularly sampled in some domain, and the data aligns with those samples. It sounds like your particles are all over the place with locations defined by some array (and presumably an amplitude array somewhere as well?). If I understand correctly, this is hard to deal with

Comment: Well, this is part of my confusion. I know the two point auto-correlation function can be computed for a set of particles. It's done in galaxy surveys all of the time. 

"For a given distance, the two-point autocorrelation function is a function of one variable (distance) which describes the probability that two galaxies are separated by this particular distance. It can be thought of as a lumpiness factor - the higher the value for some distance scale, the more lumpy the universe is at that distance scale." 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(astronomy)

Comment: And if I can compute the auto-correlation function, then the power spectrum is just the fourier transform of that. So in theory I believe it is possible to compute the power spectrum for a population of particles with known 3D coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't quite work the way you are setting it out...

You need a function, lets call it `f(x, y, z)`, that describes the density of mass in space. In your case, you can consider the galaxies as point masses, so you will have a delta function centered at the location of each galaxy. It is for this function that you can calculate the three-dimensional autocorrelation, from which you could calculate the power spectrum.

If you want to use numpy to do that for you, you are first going to have to discretize your function. A possible mock example would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

space = np.zeros((100, 100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)

x, y, z = np.random.randint(100, size=(3, 1000))
space[x, y, z] += 1

space_ps = np.abs(np.fft.fftn(space))
space_ps *= space_ps

space_ac = np.fft.ifftn(space_ps).real.round()
space_ac /= space_ac[0, 0, 0]
```

And now `space_ac` holds the three-dimensional autocorrelation function for the data set. This is not quite what you are after, and to get you one-dimensional correlation function you would have to average the values on spherical shells around the origin:

```
dist = np.minimum(np.arange(100), np.arange(100, 0, -1))
dist *= dist
dist_3d = np.sqrt(dist[:, None, None] + dist[:, None] + dist)
distances, _ = np.unique(dist_3d, return_inverse=True)
values = np.bincount(_, weights=space_ac.ravel()) / np.bincount(_)

plt.plot(distances[1:], values[1:])
```

There is another issue with doing things yourself this way: when you compute the power spectrum as above, mathematically is as if your three dimensional array wrapped around the borders, i.e. point `[999, y, z]` is a neighbour to `[0, y, z]`. So your autocorrelation could show two very distant galaxies as close neighbours. The simplest way to deal with this is by making your array twice as large along every dimension, padding with extra zeros, and then discarding the extra data.

Alternatively you could use `scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate` with `mode='constant'` to do all the dirty work for you.

Comment: @ Jaime. I'll give this a shot - all great information, thank you!

Comment: @astromax , I am trying to extract the power spectrum of a 2D binary data (which is a map of vegetation in semi-arid areas), to get the typical distance between vegetation patches, is this method here can be adapted also to a dataset such as `np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1000))`?

Comment: @Ohm, this should definitely be able to be applied to your 2D binary dataset. I can't really post a python solution here for your specific problem, but I would also recommend looking into astroml for computing the two-point autocorrelation function (http://www.astroml.org/user_guide/correlation_functions.html; which is essentially the fourier transform of the power spectrum). This will give you something like typical inter-plant spacing. Also consider clustering. This can also give you an idea of the typical distances between objects.

Comment: I am trying to do a similar thing, but I don't understand some details. Could anyone please elaborate why `space_ac /= space_ac[0, 0, 0]` is used?