# Power spectrum of 2D binary data on Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft, correlation

I have a 2D binary data representing a map of vegetation (ones ark existence of vegetation, zeros for bare soil). I would like to compute the power spectrum of such a data, and I am interested in getting the typical distance between vegetation patches. I understand that the ways to do it are fft or 2 points autocorrelation functions.

I have read this thread and played with it - [Power Spectrum and Autocorrelation of Data in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819909/power-spectrum-and-autocorrelation-of-data-in-numpy)

So my data would be something as
`space = np.random.randint(100, size=(3, 1000))`

Is it right to take the fft of this data in this way?

```
space_ps = np.abs(np.fft.fftn(space))
space_ps *= space_ps

space_ac = np.fft.ifftn(space_ps).real.round()
space_ac /= space_ac[0, 0]
```

And how later can I reduce this to 1D array that gives me the probability of finding a certain distance between vegetation patches in my dataset?

Basic code for creating 2D binary dataset

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = int(10)
space = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.uint8)
x, y = np.random.randint(N, size=(2, 100))
space[x, y] += 1

plt.ion()
plt.clf()
ext = [0,N,0,N]
im=plt.imshow(space,origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', extent=ext, cmap='Greens')
cbar=plt.colorbar()
title=plt.title('Vegetation patches')
plt.draw()
```

Comment: The patches could be disconnected, like farm lands that are cut off from one another by roads. Do you want the average distance between all of the single patches (which correspond to a single element inside `space`) or the average distance between grouped vegetation areas (which means that a vegetation area is a collection of single elements that are connected on either the N, E, S or W sides (or a different criterion)? In the latter case, are you looking for the distance between the centers of these areas or the shortest distance, i.e. from the edges of those areas?

Comment: @OliverW.  - I want the average distance between all of the single patches. The idea is that there is a typical distance between the single patches of vegetation (and the vegetation patches have a typical size).